# How to redirect spam referral traffic to avoid biased visit statistics?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I want to permanently redirect any traffic coming from a website I deem to be spam referrals. For example, if HTTP_REFERRER is 'spamsite1.com' I don't want the page to be rendered but to permanently redirect to say "www.getoutofhere.com".

With apache I would use mod_rewrite but how can I accomplish this with a rails (unicorn) server running in Heroku?

I could use API such as [aksmet](http://akismet.com/plans/) to check and create a list of spam sites based on referrer. My concern is a 25% of my traffic is coming from such a site and I don't want 100% bounce rate to be added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Heroku, I would use [rack-rewrite](https://github.com/jtrupiano/rack-rewrite) middleware to accomplish this redirect/rewrites.